# Fetching data from a site requiring POST data?

Tags: php, post, external, fetch

There's a very simple website containing just a few elements of which I'd like to retrieve a table. Previously I've used file_get_contents('http://www.example.com') for this exact purpose and extracted the piece of information I needed through explode and str_replace commands, which worked fine.

However, **this website requires POST data before it will display the table I require. I know only the name and id of the select boxes through which the data is submitted, as well as the 'option value' I need to submit.**

Another thing is that **the second select box only appears once the first one has been dealt with**, much like the table only appears once an option has been chosen for both.

How do I go about fetching the table?

Thanks in advance!

*Abstract (and poor) representation of the site serving the table:*

```
    <select id='select_box_1' name='first select box'>
      <option value='option1_1'>Thing one</option>
      <option value='option1_2'>Second thing</option>
      <option value='option1_3'>Thing number three</option>
    </select>

    NOTE: Selecting an option will spawn:

    <select id='select_box_2' name='second select box'>
      <option value='option2_1'>First thing</option>
      <option value='option2_2'>Second choice</option>
      <option value='option2_3'>The third option</option>
    </select>

    NOTE: Selecting an option will spawn the table I need.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) are some examples

Comment: Thanks, (note to self:) this webpage further explains using curl for POST requests: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the site you are trying to scrape is storing the value of the first select in a session after a POST to populate/show the second select. This means it can't be done with a single request.

You'll have to use a PHP Http client that support POST and Sessions/Cookies. [Zend_Http_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) from ZendFramework supports both so is a good candidate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to find out if the page uses a session, other than just seeing if curl works?