# Automated Download of URL Content from site requiring cookies

Tags: php, matlab, cookies, automation, download

I'm attempting to automatically download content at regular time intervals from a site requiring users to log in. The content I'm seeking to download is a small .js file (<10 kb).

As the site will display the desired data only when I'm logged in, I'm unable to simply use functions such as **urlwrite** (in MATLAB) to download the data.

I'm not sure whether the **libcurl** library  in PHP would be able to solve the problem easily.

As suggested in the answer to this similar question ([Fetching data from a site requiring POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244795/fetching-data-from-a-site-requiring-post-data)), I've tried to use the Zend_Http_Client, but haven't been able to get it to work.

In summary, I'd like help on automatically downloading URL content from a site requiring user log-in (and presumably submission of cookies).

---

In addition to this, I'd appreciate advice on which software is best for automated download of such data at regular time intervals.

*(If you do require the exact URL I am trying to download from to test a solution, please leave a comment below.)*

Comment: CURL will allow you to login and then follow the redirect and download the content, and not too difficult to write, look into the setopt COOKIEJAR etc http://uk.php.net/manual/en/curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of login the site uses. If it uses HTTP authentication you use curl option CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH (see setopt, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) Otherwise, as said, you use COOKIEJAR and possible COOKIEFILE.

Another option is the standalone utility wget. The FAQ contains a nice explanation of both login methods http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#password-protected

If this is the first time you use curl: don't forget to set CURL_RETURNTRANSFER to true (if false the content is send to stdout) and CURL_HEADER to false to get the content without headers.

Answer (score 0):

I your only concern is login, rather than cookies in general. Check the answer to this question : [How do I use libcurl to login to a secure website and get at the html behind the login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550016/how-do-i-use-libcurl-to-login-to-a-secure-website-and-get-at-the-html-behind-the)

Comment: Thanks! For the problem in question, I am seeking to repeatedly (and automatically) download data from the URL (at intervals of ~1 min) once my computer is on. Will the libcurl solution require me to login each time I switch the computer on again?

Comment: It seems so, but not sure. Can you give it a try and share your findings.

Comment: Ok sure, will post here when I get the solution.